# How can I bottom-align buttons from two Bootstrap columns inside card?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have two columns inside a card, each of which contains a title, some text, and a button. I'd like both buttons to be bottom-aligned. I can achieve this when I only have one column, but when I add a second column and nest inside of a row, the buttons no longer bottom align. Is there an easy fix to this issue in Bootstrap 5?

Here is a MWE:

```
            <div class="card">
              <h5 class="card-header"> Header </h5>
              <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">

                <div class="row">

                  <div class="col-6">
                    <h6 class="card-title">Sub-header 1</h6>
                    <p class="form-text"> description 1 </p>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-6">
                    <h6 class="card-title">Sub-header 2</h6>
                    <p class="form-text"> description 2 </p>
                  </div>

                </div>


                <!-- Buttons -->
                <div class="row">

                  <div class="col-6">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary mt-auto align-self-start" role="button">Click!</a>
                  </div>


                  <div class="col-6">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary mt-auto align-self-start" role="button">Or Me?</a>
                  </div>

                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out how to do this. Maybe it is obvious, but the issue was that my buttons were no longer direct children of the card-body. The fix is to add `mt-auto` to the *row* div:

```
                <!-- Buttons -->
                <div class="row mt-auto ">

                  <div class="col-6">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary align-self-start" role="button">Click!</a>
                  </div>


                  <div class="col-6">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary align-self-start" role="button">Or Me?</a>
                  </div>
```